# Evidar a mudança dos caracteres especiais na escrita da URI

Tags: java, android, string, url, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou utilizando a API do google maps no meu projeto mas estou tendo um pequeno problema.

para montar a URL estou usando um URI que se concatena com buildUpon assim com ono exemplo abaixo.

```
Uri uriBase = Uri.parse(urlBase).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(language, "pt-BR")
                    .appendQueryParameter(units, "metric")
                    .appendQueryParameter(origins, "Washington,DC")
                    .appendQueryParameter(destinations, "New+York+City,NY")
                    .appendQueryParameter(key, GOOGLE_API_KEY)
                    .build();
```

ate ai tudo bem, o problema e que são com os caracteres especiais como "," e " ". Eles são convertidos para sua forma `url encoding`ficando algo parecido com %2C ou %2B, o que pode acabar impedindo que o google maps identifique o endereço retornando vazio o json, gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de impedir essa conversão.

Comment: "(...)  o que pode acabar impedindo (...)": Pode ou impede mesmo?

Comment: Atualmente não obtive problemas, mas até o ano passado não estava conseguindo retorno dessa forma, o que me deixa com um pé atrás nesse caso.

Comment: Em principio o correcto será usar(sempre) um *encoded URI*.